# Filter out data loaded into dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssas, bids

I know it is recommended to build dimension using a view on source table because it allows to make changes to the dimension contents without opening the SSAS project. However, I cannot create a view in the source system.

How can I load only a subset of data into a dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **named query** can be used to filter out unnecessary dimension members. Conceptually it is similar to a database view and the source RDBMS will take care of data processing (e.g. filtering it), but it is defined in the SSAS project.

1. Open the data source view.
2. Right-click on the dimension source table and choose `Replace Table / With New Named Query...` from the context menu.
3. Add a `WHERE` clause to the query and make any other changes you need:

[image: SSAS - named query]